# Can I submit an app to the App Store that needs a hardware device not available in the market(yet)?

Tags: ios, applications, hardware, app-store-connect, developer-program

I am working on a project where im developing a circuit (Raspberry Pi) and an iOS app where the app is used to communicate (via Bluetooth Low Energy) to the Raspberry, only to setup some credentials. The circuit is a prototype, my question is, if I send the app to review will they reject it because the reviewer does not have the Raspberry device to test it?

Comment: Hardware not being available in market generally wouldn’t be a reason for the app to get rejected, but you may be asked to send in a prototype to the review team. Alternatively, you could also be asked to make video demonstrating the use of the said device (speaking from similar personal experiences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can submit such apps! I have done so before and got them approved.

You’ll probably be asked to provide more information about your setup, or be asked to provide a video of you actually using an iOS device to control the hardware.